# Time Value of Money NumPy Functions, Working with Varying Floating Rates

Tags: python, numpy, finance

I would like to ask about the NumPy functions such as NumPy.fv(). I am aware of how to execute this function but ONLY for interest rates that are fixed. I would like to ask what if the rates are floating/varying interest rate?

For example,
ABC deposited $1,000,000 into a bank, the bank pays a floating rate annually as shown:
[1.2%, 1%, 1.8%, 1.2%, 0.9%]. What is the total amount ABC will receive after 5 years?

What I understand is through the use of for-loops and I know how to work this out via Excel but I have been scratching my head around this if the TVM functions may be implemented inside this for-loop to work out the final compounded amount after 5 years?

Comment: FYI (not an answer): You mention `numpy.fv`.  That function is deprecated, and will be removed from NumPy 1.20.  `fv` and the other deprecated NumPy financial functions are available in the `numpy_financial` library: https://pypi.org/project/numpy-financial/

Comment: Oh right thanks ! I am using the older version of NumPy as of now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really need anything complicated for this:

```
principal = 1000000
rates =  [0.012, 0.01, 0.018, 0.012, 0.009]
for r in rates:
    principal = principal*(1+r)
print("${:,.2f}".format(principal))
```

Output:

```
$1,062,481.42
```

Comment: Thanks ! I guess in this case we may not apply the FV function at all? Due to the fact that interest rates are not constant?

Comment: @funkymickey Indeed not; as far as I can tell - `fv()` can't handle floating interest rates.

Comment: Gotcha. Just to check, the parameter (1 + r) is basically like saying (100% + r%) which gives you your new total % now ?

Comment: @funkymickey Yes. Basically, the outstanding balance of any investment/loan after 1 period is the original amount ('principal`, in this case) mulitplied by (1+interest rate for that period, expressed as a fraction).